# Remove newline characters in file

Tags: perl, awk, sed, gawk, tr

I have a text file with comma seperated values which has newline characters in the column values.  So it makes the column data split to next line causing data issues.

#### Sample data

```
"604","56-1203802","xx","VEN","null","50","1","20","Nï¿½
jTï"
"5526","841328305","yyINC","VEN","null","50","1","20","~R¿½Kï¿½ï
¿½ï¿½}("
"604","561203802","C","VEN",,"null","50","1","20","2ï½aï¿½ï¿½"
```

#### Expected Output

```
"604","56-1203802","xx","VEN","null","50","1","20","Nï¿½jTï"
"5526","841328305","yyINC","VEN","null","50","1","20","~R¿½Kï¿½ï¿½ï¿½}("
"604","561203802","C","VEN",,"null","50","1","20","2ï½aï¿½ï¿½"
```

I need to remove the newlines inside double-quoted strings.

I tried the below awk command to remove it, but it is not working as expected.

```awk
gawk -v RS='"' 'NR % 2 == 0 { gsub(/\n/, "") } { printf("%s%s", $0, RT) }' infile.txt > outfile.txt
```

The required result would be to remove the LF and CR characters from the data.

I tried solutions for similar question posted, but not working for me.

Newline characters in the file are not visible unless copied to Notepad++ when it shows as CR LF.

Comment: Please, do not post an image of the data, we're not going to type it out and use for testing.

Comment: @JamesBrown Yes,changed now.Please take a look

Comment: Please add code tags for sample data rather than quotes.

Comment: You got referred to the answer [last time you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46378760/1745001).Read the answer and ask a specific, new question if you have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this `sed`:

```
sed ':loop; /" *$/!{N;s/\n//g; b loop}' file
```